# How to change the size of the dialog?

Tags: java, jface

I created a dialog class:

```
myDailog extends Dialog 
    public myDailog (Shell parentShell, String tatgetEntity) {
        super(parentShell)
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent) {
        final Composite body = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        ...//some logic to create tableViewwer
    }
```

The problem that I can't change the size of the dialog (stretch the windows).
Do I need to use different dialog?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: The framework is jface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use this public method to enable the dialog to be resizable:

```
public void setResizable(boolean resizable)
```

ps I'm assuming you are using this [java.awt.Dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html) class

Comment: In that case use: `setShellStyle(SWT.RESIZE);` it is a method inherited from `class org.eclipse.jface.window.Window`

Answer (score 2):

Override the `isResizable` method of `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog`:

```
@Override
protected boolean isResizable()
{
  return true;
}
```